# What do these 3 numbers mean on the copyright page?

Tags: publishing, copyright

[image: Photograph: "Percy Jackson and the sea of monsters" copyright page]

Text:

> published in the USA by Hyperion Books for Children 2005
>
> Published in Great Britain by Puffin Books 2005
>
> This edition published 2013
>
> **020**

What do the 3 numbers mean?

Comment: Probably the print run. That is, this is the 20th time this edition has been reprinted. If you really want to know, write to the publisher. They'll likely explain it to you.